# Bootstrap find DIV height and place new DIV

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

articles updates from database and each article with different text length, locate on under `<P>` tag . Bootstrap `<div>` having `col-lg-3` class as flowing image

[image]

But I want to find most top place (min height from top) and  place next DIV tag(new article paragraph) as follows. this logic should be different with [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239930/bootstrap-row-height-change-with-individual-div)

[image]

```
<div class="row">
<?php
    foreach ($article as $add) {
        echo "<div class='col-lg-3'>";
        echo "<p class=''><b>(". $add->article_id .")</b> ". $add->content . "</p><hr>";
        echo "</div>";
    }      
?>    
</div>
```

Comment: Something like that? http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Lightweight-Responsive-Pinterest-Layout-with-jQuery-Waterfall/

Comment: this question is not duplicated. @Mosh's solution is the better idea